# MySQL - Storing groups the user is in

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I have a website that assigns user to groups and each user can be in unlimited number of groups.

**Example:**

User A:

- Chess Group
- String Orchestra Group
- Basketball Group

User B

- Football Group
- Chess Group

---

Currently, my table structure is as follows:

Table: `login`

- id (auto-increment)
- username
- password

---

I'm considering storing PHP `serialise` array by having a new row in the table `login`. However, editing a user's groups would be difficult as I would have to unserialise it then serialise it again.

Or would it be better to store the groups in a new table entirely?

What is the **fastest** and **most efficient** way to store the groups that each user belongs to?

This method needs to be easy when updating the groups and also fast when querying.

Hope that there's a better method than `serialise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is called a many-to-many relationship (each group has multiple members, and each person is a member of multiple groups.) The usual approach would be to have a second table for groups, indexed by a unique group ID and storing all information about each group *except* membership, and a third table for membership.

The membership table (known as an "intersection entity") has as its columns the primary keys of the other two tables, that is, `login_id` and `group_id`. Its primary key would be the concatenation of both its columns (`PRIMARY KEY (login_id, group_id)`) and each of its columns would also be a foreign key referencing one of the other tables.

This situation is well-known and well-studied, and in fact is about the second thing you learn when you begin to study normalization of database tables.

An example might be

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(255),
  password VARCHAR(255),
  -- other columns go here
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE groups
(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  description TEXT,
  -- other columns go here
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE membership
(
  login_id INT,
  group_id INT,
  -- possibly more columns, or perhaps not
  PRIMARY KEY (login_id, group_id),
  CONSTRAINT member_user FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES login (id),
  CONSTRAINT member_group FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (id)
);
```

The foreign keys on `membership` ensure that a user cannot be a member of a group unless both the user and the group already exist. The composite primary key for `membership` ensures that a given person can belong to a given group only once; neglecting this point can lead to some really bizarre problems when you try to query the tables later.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post! :)

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example on the intersection entity using my situation? Thanks!

Comment: This link might help you. All you need is to join the table properly
http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/